MongoDB Atlas Search with VectorSearch and filters
Take a query like this... (shortened the query for clarity)
[
  {
    "$vectorSearch": {
      "index": "myVectorIndex",
      "path": "vectors.myVectorPath",
      "filter": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "name": {
              "$in": ["Bill Gates"]
            }
          },
          {
            "$or": [
              {
                "field-one": true
              },
              {
                "field-two": true
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "queryVector": [
        -0.007456403,
        -0.01990008,
        0.013442357,
        0.060729556,
        ...  
        ...
        ...

When I use this query with Bill Gates, I get what I'm looking for. bill gates will bring zero results (lower case), Bill G will also bring zero results (partial string). The name search value must be 100% identical to what's in the database.
My goal, is to use the same query, with the queryVectors but search on name using partial case-insensitive strings so that bill or Bill Ga or bill gates finds the Bill Gate name.
How can this be achieved?

In your pre-filter query you're using $in that compares Strings using BSON type comparison. In this case:

By default, MongoDB uses the simple binary comparison to compare strings.

So you're right: you can't make spelling mistakes, case has is sensitive etc.
The solution to your problem is to use Atlas Search (Apache Lucene under the hood) and mix the results of your search with this vector search, using reciprocal rank fusion, as described in this doc: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-vector-search/tutorials/reciprocal-rank-fusion
